# numerical linear algebra orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

introduction to numerical liner algebra.
I am not sure how to proceed in this problem. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

1.)i am not sure how we ended with a 1 for the proof. I am not sure what the definition of $\|Q\|_2$ is. Is it the same as a matrix norm?

Comment: You know that $\mathbf Q^\top=\mathbf Q^{-1}$, no?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  What exactly is your definition for $\|M\|_2$ for a matrix $M$?

Comment: I know that $QQ^\top=I$ but i am not sure how we ended with a 1 for the proof. I am not sure what the definition of $\|Q\|_2$ is. Is it the same as a matrix norm?

Comment: What resource are you using? I'm sure they define it as a matrix norm of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you hit some roadblocks, and then failed to make a reasonable followup attempt.  As such, you might find it useful that I've outlined my thought process towards this problem.

If you want to prove something about $\|\cdot\|_2$, you need to know its definition, and you need to work with that definition (I don't understand how you were planning to approach the problem without this piece of information). There are two common (equivalent) definitions for $\|\cdot\|_2$, as you're using it here.  One (sightly less common) definition is
$$
\|M\|_2 = \sigma_1(M) = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(M^TM)}
$$
If that's your definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$, then $\|Q\|_2 = 1$ is immediately obvious since $Q^TQ = I$.

A more likely definition in your context is
$$
\|M\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Mx\|_2
$$
where $x$ is a vector and $\|x\|_2,\|Mx\|_2$ are the usual vector $2$-norms.

At this point, you found that the property $QQ^T = I$ was not particularly useful (at least not directly).  I agree.  The followup is to ask *what other properties* do orthogonal matrices have?  A property that you almost certainly have *somewhere* in your text or notes is the fact that for any vector $x$, we have
$$
\|Qx\|_2 = \|x\|_2
$$
Using this fact and the second definition, conclude that $\|Q\|_2 = 1$.

Now, note that $Q^{-1}$ is **also** orthogonal (why?).  It follows that $\|Q^{-1}\|_2 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understand now..... For the part to prove that $\|Q^{-1}\| _2 = 1$. Is it because $\|Q^{-1}x\|=\|x\|_2$ as well?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$